# c# code cents into dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a c# code that allows user input that changes cents into dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. Using 1492 and 777 to test the program. I am new to coding and c# so any help would be great.

This is what I have so far. I just do not think I am doing this right.

```
int pennies = 1492;
int dollar = pennies / 100; 
int quarter = (pennies / 100) * 4;
int dime = (pennies / 100) * 10;

Console.WriteLine("result is {0} dollars, {1} quarters, {2} dimes", dollar, quarter, dime);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you tell us what should be the result of 1492 pennies?

Comment: Your are not considering the remainder in pennies of your operations.

Comment: I do not know the whole result, I know that it's 14 dollars, 56 quarters.

Comment: How do I consider the remainder of pennies in the problem?

Comment: And the calc for dimes and quarter is wrong

Comment: 14 dollars, 56 quarters.... How's that possible? Can you explain the calculation? We can suggest the code changes based on that.

Comment: 1492 pennies (1492 / 100 = $14.92 ) I have to then take that and determine how many quarters I can get from $14.92 which would be 56 = $14 but total would be 59 quarters, but I cant get that with the code. I would have 17 cents left over where I can get 1 dime, 1 nickel with 2 pennies left. But when I run the code I get different answers.

Comment: If you are looking for *total* quarters and dimes (`59` and `149`): `int quarter = (pennies / 25);`and `int dime = (pennies / 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A penny (or cent) is 1/100 of a dollar, a quarter is a 1/4 and a dime is a 1/10 . You don't get a whole number of dollars from 1492 pennies but only 14, the remainder are 92 pennies that contains 3 quarters that you should add to the 56 quarters from the 14 dollars and again in the 92 pennies you get other 9 dimes to add to the 14 * 10 from the whole dollars. The remainder are 2 pennies

So 1492 pennies are composed of

```
14 dollars and 92 pennies
or 59 quarters and 17 pennies
or 149 dimes and 2 pennies

int pennies = 1492;
int dollar = pennies / 100;
int quarter = (pennies / 25);
int dime = (pennies / 10);
int remainder = pennies - (dime * 10);

Console.WriteLine("result is {0} dollars, {1} quarters, {2} dimes, {3} remainder", dollar, quarter, dime, remainder);
```

Instead if you want to get the single values that you can obtain from the input value you could write something like this

```
dollar = pennies / 100;
quarter = (pennies - (dollar * 100)) / 25;
dime = (pennies - (dollar * 100 + quarter * 25)) / 10;
int nickel = (pennies - (dollar * 100 + quarter * 25 + dime * 10)) / 5;
remainder = (pennies - (dollar * 100 + quarter * 25 + dime * 10 + nickel * 5));

Console.WriteLine("result is {0} dollars, {1} quarters, {2} dimes, {3} nickel, {4} remainder", dollar, quarter, dime, nickel, remainder);
```

Comment: Thank You Steve! So my calculations were off. How would I adjust the code to all user input of pennies?

Comment: and for nickels would I just do int nickel ( pennies / 5); ?

Comment: or the double of dimes

Comment: so my answer could read 14 dollars, 59 quarters, 149 dimes, 298 nickels, and 2 remaining pennies?

Comment: The correct answers should be you start with 1492 pennies, which gets you 14 dollars and 92 cents, from there you can get 3 quarters (92 cents - 75 cents = 17 cents), then that gets you 1 dime, 1 nickel and 2 remaining pennies. ANSWER should be 14 dollars, 3 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, and 2 remaining pennies